# python: Summing up two numbers of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is what I get so far, How can I make it return a False when there is no such values?

```
def pairSum(l, s):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    for i in l:
        if l[a]+l[b] == s:
            return True
        a=a+1
        b=b+1
```

Edit: I just realized that this function would only find two consecutive numbers that add to s. I was meant to create a function that determines if any two numbers in a list add up to s, not two consecutive numbers. Sorry for the misleading information.

Comment: Where did you write "return False" statement?  Your program cannot return it unless it has it. Also, how about using "range" function in your code? And parse values using their index in the list. Place "return False" after for loop with indentation matched.

Comment: Please explain more detailed what you are trying to archive.

Comment: Can you put more detailed info, what you want to do? What I understand little from this question is you want to verify given sum is equal to two concurrent element from the list?

Comment: I am trying to determine if there is a pair of numbers in the list l that adds to s

Comment: Do you try to find any combination that adds up to the value s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f = lambda x,y: x+y

def func(l, s):
    for i in range(len(l)-1):
        if f(l[i],l[i+1]) == s:
            return True
    return False
```

This will return `True` if the addition of two consecutative numbers of the list results in `s` and `False` otherwise.

If you want to check if the addition of any two numbers in `l` adds to `s` then

```
from itertools import combinations
def sumPairs(l, s):
    for a, b in combinations(lst, 2):
        if a+b == s:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: `for i in range(len(l))`, using `enumerate()` to just discard the value looks strange. And if you set the range to `len-1` you can avoid the `try: ... except: ...` block.

Comment: This will return False on the very first check that fails, instead of checking all values.